# form post with ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

Hi everyone So I try to send form data integred by a ajax json function to a node server.

And I try the official code : https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ajax-and-forms/  and 
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

And my code :

```
<script>
// Attach a submit handler to the form
$( ".formdeleteuserwork" ).submit(function( event ) {

  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( "input[name='idpublic']" ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( url, { idpublic: term } );

  // Put the results in a div

});
</script>
```

and the html :

```
<form action="/formdeleteuserwork" id="formdeleteuserwork" class="formdeleteuserwork" method="post" style="position: absolute; top: -656px; left: -298px;"><input style="position: relative; top: 224px; left: -518px;" name="idpublic" value="something" src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/dfsfsdgfd/gfdsgsdfg.png" class="removeinvit" type="image"></form>
```

This code doesn't work : the page is refreshing.

Can you help me. Thanks !

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: @Andreas This code doesn't work. The form is sending normally with page refresh.

Comment: Are errors shown in the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: Nothing in javascript console   @wigi

Comment: Is this form created dynamically? If so, you should attach event handler differently as the element might not have been created when you were attaching the handler: `$('document').on('submit', 'form.formdeleteuserwork', function() { ... });`

Comment: How are you creating the form? And how do you submit it, is there a submit button?

Comment: So I create the form with ajax dynamicaly @wigi and The input is the submit button (is a image).

Comment: @Criss So I try this :  $('.formdeleteuserwork').on('submit', 'form.formdeleteuserwork', function() {
  // Stop form from submitting normally
  preventDefault();
 
  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( "input[name='idpublic']" ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );
 
  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( url, { idpublic: term } );
 
  // Put the results in a div

});    but This code doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote, that you create the form dynamically, you will need live event listeners instead of the default event listeners. Live event listeners do listen to any events on dynamically created nodes.

So you will need to replace your listener with this:

```
$( document ).on('submit', '.formdeleteuserwork', function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // your code

});
```